# Bootstrap navigation tab showing the both tabs in the same time

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to create Page with a 2 tabs when the first Tab is the Form itself and the second is a preview of it.

For now I only have the main page organized but it shows the both tabs content in the same time.

What I should add to fix it and what should be added on the Form.php and preview.php to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>FORM</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#myTab a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#add">ADD CAMPAIGN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#preview">PREVIEW</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="add" class="tab-pane active">
        <?php include('form.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="preview" class="tab-pane">
        <?php include('preview.php');?>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you applied the active class yourself? The one on your li that is

Comment: you mean if i wrote the form.php by my self? yes

Comment: Then your issue might be there, because as far as I'm concerned the class "Active" is the one setting the tab as "shown" have you tried removeing the class to see if it works? (Remove the active class from the LI element only)

Comment: The problem here is <?php include();?>. I am trying to find an answer as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#linkOne").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#preview").removeClass("active");
      $("#add").addClass("active");
  });
  $("#linkTwo").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#add").removeClass("active");
      $("#preview").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-pane{
  display: none;
}

.active
{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="bs-example">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li><a id="linkOne" href="#add">ADD CAMPAIGN</a></li>
    <li><a id="linkTwo" href="#preview">PREVIEW</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="add" class="tab-pane active">
        tab content 1
    </div>
    <div id="preview" class="tab-pane">
        tab content 2
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben what u did is working but when I put some PHP tags to the pages it's not working again.. :( here's all the code  (form and previews isn't ready yet)

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#linkOne").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#preview").removeClass("active");
      $("#add").addClass("active");
  });
  $("#linkTwo").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#add").removeClass("active");
      $("#preview").addClass("active");
  });
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="bs-example">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li><a id="linkOne" href="#add">ADD CAMPAIGN</a></li>
    <li><a id="linkTwo" href="#preview">PREVIEW</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="add" class="tab-pane active">
        tab content 1

        <?php include('form.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="preview" class="tab-pane">
        tab content 2
         <?php include('preview.php');?>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**form.php**

```
<form method="post"  action="form.php">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th> 
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type = "text" name="name" id="name">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> 
                                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type = "text" name="email" id="email">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> 
                                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea type = "text" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        <table>
                            <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
```

**preview.php**

```
<table>
                            <tr>
                                <th> 
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> 
                                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> 
                                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: **style.css**        .tab-pane{
  display: none;
}

.active
{
  display: block !important;
}

Comment: how it looks...   add campaing   [link]http://gyazo.com/861ca4fcf983594b515f0cd48b29e02a